# Java - object creation and visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Given the following code:

```
class MyObj{
   AtomicLong counter;

   public MyObj(){
       count = new AtomicLong();
   }
}

MyObj obj = new MyObj();
// start a few threads that referencey obj and access counter
```

I would like to know if there is a potential scenario here, that the created threads will see the state of MyObj as incomplete, due to compiler reodering/inlining? For instance, they might see `counter  = null`, or counter partially created, as it is not a final field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two situations:

- if you start the threads ***after*** `MyObj obj = new MyObj()`, there is a happens-before relationship that guarantees that the threads will all see the correctly constructed object
- if you start the threads ***before***, there is no guarantee of anything (they could observe `obj == null` or `obj != null && obj.counter == null` or `obj != null && obj.counter != null`).